# Does Ox or Bull Semen have Taurine?

Tags: zoology, physiology

Numerous skeptical communities have debunked the claim that [Red Bull](https://www.redbull.com/us-en/) has bull semen (including [Snopes](http://www.snopes.com/food/ingredient/bullsemen.asp), and [Skeptics.StackExchange](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/2039/3835). But, none have said whether or not it is even possible.

Taurine, according to Wikipedia, is "widely distributed in animal tissues." But, does it get excreted through semen, and has anyone found it in bull semen?

Comment: I'm unsure as to why this question is about to be closed as unclear. I don't think it could possibly be any more clear.

Answer (score 3):

Taurine is widely found in meats and fish. It was named from the Latin word for bull (*taurus*) because it was first discovered in ox bile.

From http://www.frontresearch.com/news/china-taurine-market-is-fluctuating/

> In recent years, the global Taurine consumption has kept growing with an GAGR of 5.5%, more than 50 kilotons in 2014.

I have no idea how much taurine is in bull semen but even if it contains a great deal, do you really think Red Bull will be using that as a source? Can you actually imagine a way of getting bull semen to extract it? The ratio of bulls to cows or steers is very small. The only reason a farmer or breeder keeps a bull is for breeding and many cows are artificially insemination from a limited number (relatively speaking) of bulls with the desired qualities.

All this is to explain to you that your question is  completely inane and pointless. I can't believe anybody would actually think it could happen.

Answer (score 2):

I found a few papers about the function/concentration/localization of taurine/hypotaurine in the male reproductive system of various species:

[The taurine and hypotaurine content of human semen:](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/1601750)

> Hypotaurine, an antioxidant, may play an important role in protecting sperm from reactive oxygen species.

[Protective effect of taurine from osmotic stress on chimpanzee spermatozoa:](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/7149852)

> These results suggest that taurine plays an osmoregulatory role in chimpanzee spermatozoa, which possibly involves stabilization of the cell membrane.

[Taurine maintains and stimulates motility of hamster sperm during capacitation in vitro:](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/536709)

> These results suggest that in addition to its importance for motility taurine might stimulate capacitation. The mechanism through which taurine supports and stimulates motility is not yet known, but its use results in the first relatively “defined” in vitro capacitation medium for hamster sperm.

[Hypotaurine in spermatozoa and genital secretions and its production by oviduct epithelial cells in vitro:](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/7650134)

> Taurine and/or hypotaurine are necessary compounds for sperm capacitation, fertilization and embryo development. Hypotaurine has a protective role against peroxidative damage... Hypotaurine and taurine were quantified in spermatozoa and seminal and tubal fluid of various species, and in secretions by oviduct epithelial cell layers in vitro. Significant amounts of taurine and hypotaurine were identified.

These are but a few papers I found in a cursory search. You can also see this [article](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/1731369) for what seems to be a comprehensive overview of the "physiological actions of taurine". Even though I haven't found any direct measurements of bulls, it seems safe to say that, given its function and ubiquitous nature, bull semen contains taurine.

Comment: I too don't doubt bull semen contains taurine. As you mention, it's ubiquious, found in most animal tissue. All members of Felidae **require** taurine in their diet as they're unable to synthesize it as most mammals can. But I can't imagine felines, even a Siberian tiger, relying on bull semen for their source. When I read the OP's question, a mental picture of people trying to collect bull semen came to mind. :D

Comment: @Jude Ha! I just read the question as whether or not bull semen contains taurine; the stuff about Red Bull seems ancillary. I only posted this answer because I found that article with a quick search but, truly, I know about as little as is possible about this topic.

Comment: Which is why I told him in my answer that his question was both inane and pointless. I was doing my best as being polite as is fitting for a fellow Canadian.

Comment: Inanity is quite common in questions here.

Comment: I'm beginning to notice that! There are some but much less on Gardening SE and Seasoned Advice SE as people ask for advice or to honestly learn how to do something, for the most part.